# NO EJB found in .war

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I've created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse.  I have 2 beans, 1 @Entity and the other @Stateless.  I've deployed the war to Geronimo 2.2.1 with Tomcat 6 with a warning:

```
Unresolved ejb reference "com.myconnection.servlet.AddServlet/srvc" in bean   
"GeronimoEnc".  Will attempt resolution again at runtime.
```

I have a form on a .jsp with an action to a servlet (AddServlet).  The servlet is trying to reference my @Stateless bean (via interface).  However, once I hit submit on my form to go to the servlet, I get this error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: Some objects to be injected were not found in jndi:    
[javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No EJB found for reference "com.
```

I also have my persistence.xml file in src/META-INF, I'm not positive if that's where it should be.

What could I be doing wrong?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for deploying WAR files with EJBs is fixed (but possibly not available; see the following text) in Geronimo 3.0, going by [bug report 5117](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMO-5117). Going by this report, dependency injection in 2.2.1 is likely to fail.

There is [one report on the mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/geronimo-user/201105.mbox/%3CBANLkTimxJwim9eii8a+0bvAawy1T8kyPcA@mail.gmail.com%3E), suggesting that Geronimo 3.0 M1 might be used for validating whether dependency injection works for EJBs deployed in a web-application; this is however against a query raised with respect to a failure on the same topic. Reproducing the salient contents of the mail:

---

> Łukasz:
>
> Geronimo is not able to inject @EJB
>   into a servlet. Both SLSB and my
>   serlvet are packaged in war. ... **By
>   looking at the release notes I know
>   that EJB 3.1 is supported only
>   partially**. I take it that the part
>   that is not yet implemented in
>   deploying EJBs inside war package?
>
> Ivan:
>
> Hmm, IIRC, **the EJB injection should
>   work in the M1 release, although it
>   have some bugs in EJB 3.1
>   integration.** I would suggest to use
>   the latest trunk codes (just update
>   some codes to try to work around the
>   address binding issue on the building
>   machine, hopefully a snapshot build
>   could be generated in the next round),
>   as we got a much better TCK result
>   comparing with M1 release. JCDI
>   related packages are definitely
>   included in the latest trunk build.

Going all of the above, 3.0 M1 would be the release to attempt this at the moment, but there is surely some possibility of this feature being absent (given that bug 5117 does not appeared to be in the list of fixed bugs in the release notes).